# ADFS delegation with SAML 2.0 delegation tokens

Tags: delegation, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

I have managed to configure ADFS 2.0 as a SAML 2.0 Idp and implement a SSO scenario with Shibboleth as a SAML 2.0 SP.
Now I want to implement a delegation scenario in which ADFS will act as an Idp that issues SAML 2.0 delegation tokens for non WIF applications.
Does anyone know if this is supported?
I read that SAML 2.0 delegation is executed using the SAML ECP profile. Does ADFS 2.0 support the ECP profile?
Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 0):

ECP requires PAOS binding. If you look in the ADFS metadata, the only bindings are HTTP Redirect / POST / Artifact and SOAP.